# How can I select an address element using *byRole in React Testing Library?

Tags: unit-testing, roles, wai-aria, react-testing-library

I tried screen.queryByRole("address") but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [a table of HTML elements with their default and desired roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance), there is **no corresponding role** for `address` element. That's why [`*ByRole`](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole) query does not work. Try using other queries.